# Is this "not only...but...as well" sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Its a sentence written by a school kid.

> Not only can they (school activities) help us to be physically stronger, but can break the routine to provide relaxation as well.

Comment: Useful: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. The second phrase needs a subject or a connector to the subject in the first phrase.

> Not only can they (school activities) help us to be physically stronger, but **they** can break the routine to provide relaxation as well.

or

> Not only can they (school activities) help us to be physically stronger, but can **also** break the routine to provide relaxation as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Not only** can they (school activities) help us to be physically stronger, **but** they can break the routine to provide relaxation **as well**.

or

**Not only** can they (school activities) help us to be physically stronger, **but** they can **also** break the routine to provide relaxation.

You can either use "Not only... but... as well" or "Not only... but... also"

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper intention is expressed with:

> Not only can they (school activities) help us be physically stronger, but **they** can **also** break the routine **and** provide relaxation as well.

Note: I removed **to** from: `help us **to** be physically stronger` - there is no strike-trough option to "delete" text.